# MUI DataGrid with edit and delete action buttons not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am new to MUI and React, trying to configure a row editable `DataGrid` with edit and delete action buttons.

I copied the following code from MUI website and changed the `DataGridPro` to `DataGrid` as it appeared to me that all the row edit features are also available in the `DataGrid` version.

Essentially, I tried making the code copied from MUI website work for `DataGrid` by changing the version from Pro to the Basic, assuming that the row edit features are same in both versions and the code should work fine for `DataGrid`. I might be wrong in my understanding, please guide.

The following code displays the edit and delete buttons, but on click the row is not changed to edit mode though the cancel and save buttons are displayed. On changing the version back to `DataGridPro` everything starts working as expected.

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined";
import SaveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Save";
import CancelIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import {
  GridRowModes,
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridActionsCellItem,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {
  randomCreatedDate,
  randomTraderName,
  randomUpdatedDate,
  randomId,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

const initialRows = [
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 25,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 36,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 19,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 28,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 23,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
];

function EditToolbar(props) {
  const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    const id = randomId();
    setRows((oldRows) => [...oldRows, { id, name: "", age: "", isNew: true }]);
    setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
      ...oldModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: "name" },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Button color="primary" startIcon={<AddIcon />} onClick={handleClick}>
        Add record
      </Button>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}

EditToolbar.propTypes = {
  setRowModesModel: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setRows: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default function FullFeaturedCrudGrid() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(initialRows);
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = React.useState({});

  const handleRowEditStart = (params, event) => {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
  };

  const handleRowEditStop = (params, event) => {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
  };

  const handleEditClick = (id) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
  };

  const handleSaveClick = (id) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (id) => () => {
    setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({
      ...rowModesModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View, ignoreModifications: true },
    });

    const editedRow = rows.find((row) => row.id === id);
    if (editedRow.isNew) {
      setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
    }
  };

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
    return updatedRow;
  };

  const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel) => {
    setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 180, editable: true },
    { field: "age", headerName: "Age", type: "number", editable: true },
    {
      field: "dateCreated",
      headerName: "Date Created",
      type: "date",
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "lastLogin",
      headerName: "Last Login",
      type: "dateTime",
      width: 220,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      headerName: "Actions",
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: "actions",
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon />}
              label="Save"
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon />}
              label="Cancel"
              className="textPrimary"
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
              color="inherit"
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<EditIcon />}
            label="Edit"
            className="textPrimary"
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: 500,
        width: "100%",
        "& .actions": {
          color: "text.secondary",
        },
        "& .textPrimary": {
          color: "text.primary",
        },
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        editMode="row"
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
        onRowEditStart={handleRowEditStart}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        slots={{
          toolbar: EditToolbar,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call a direct function in the event listener if you want to pass arrgument....  use callback and call function like onClick-{()=>handleEdit(id)}

```
return [
      <GridActionsCellItem
        icon={<EditIcon />}
        label="Edit"
        className="textPrimary"
        onClick={()=>handleEditClick(id)}
        color="inherit"
      />,
      <GridActionsCellItem
        icon={<DeleteIcon />}
        label="Delete"
        onClick={()=>handleDeleteClick(id)}
        color="inherit"
      />,
    ];
```